# Can I change or set the default Import Settings for pasting text lists in Numbers?

Tags: macos, numbers

When I paste a list with small sentences in Numbers the default **Import Settings** is "Fixed Width" and the lines are distributed in several columns while I would like them to be pasted in a single column.

Here is an example list of this behaviour:

```
I have short curly hair.
You have long curly hair.
This girt has long straight hair.
This boy has short straight hair.
```

I can use the **table data was imported and can be adjusted** pop-up or the **Adjust Import Settings...** button and change the **Import Settings** to **Delimited Tab** and then the list is adjusted in a single column.

But I use this process often and I would like to change the default import settings so that I will not have to change them manually every time.

Would this be doable?